# ERROR: IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed [scipy.integrate.quadrature]

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I am trying to integrate using scipy.integrate.romberg, but I get an error message about IndexError:

```
ERROR: IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed [scipy.integrate.quadrature]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ucmh.py", line 137, in <module>
    main()
  File "ucmh.py", line 128, in main
    avg_rho_ucmh_squared(mDM, sigma_v, 10**5)
  File "ucmh.py", line 119, in avg_rho_ucmh_squared
    return n_ucmh(z) *  integrate.romberg(integrand,0,R_h(z))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 596, in romberg
    ordsum = _difftrap(vfunc, interval, n)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 477, in _difftrap
    return 0.5*(function(interval[0])+function(interval[1]))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 94, in vfunc
    y0 = func(x[0], *args)
IndexError: 0-d arrays can't be indexed
```

What could lead to this problem?

Comment: You really need to post an example of your code so that we can help you, but to take a wild shot in the dark: numpy is expecting at least a 1D array and you are passing it a 0D array like `np.array(5)` instead of a 1D like `np.array([5])`.

Answer (score 0):

My error was that one of the inputs to the integration where an astropy.units object, so it is apparently an array, I should pass the value and not the astropy.units object